# How I draw graphics of dominoes falling?

Tags: pstricks

How I draw graphics of dominoes falling, without moviment, static draw?

Comment: Well formulated question. The so called MWE can show, how you (are trying to) draw this. ;-)

Comment: We need some context, as well as a show of effort/research.

Comment: You can try to use tikz.

Comment: I tried it on TikZ and I couldn't.I found difficulties in turning the dominoes to give the idea of perspective